# Saving and reloading tkinter entry filed values

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to develop a tkinter app. User can enter some setting values. One of the settings is a date. What I am trying to do is, user can enter settings values and save the settings and even after closing the app, after reopening,  a load button should bring back the settings values to entry field. I was successful in doing so, but for just one field. How to save multiple entry fields and reload it, including date entry? any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

my_text1 = StringVar()
my_text2 = StringVar()
my_date = StringVar()

entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=my_text1)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=my_text2)
entry2.pack()

entry3 = DateEntry(root, textvariable=my_date)
entry3.pack()


def save():
    text = my_text1.get()
    with open("saved_settings.dat", "wb") as pickle_file:
        pickle.dump(text, pickle_file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def clear():
    my_text1.set('')

def load():
    with open("saved_settings.dat", "rb") as pickle_file:
        text = pickle.load(pickle_file)
    my_text1.set(text)

Button(root, text="Save Settings", command=save).pack()
Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear).pack()
Button(root, text="Load Settings", command=load).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 'but for just one field',. seems you are only writing one field to your file, i.e `text = my_text1.get()`. you have to write the other values(my_text2, my_date) as well to be able to load them later.

Comment: create dictionary with all values and then pickle this dictinary or save it in JSON file. At start you will load dictionary from file and use values from dictionary to set values in widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary with all values and then pickle this dictinary.

At start you can load dictionary from file and use values from dictionary to set values in widgets.

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

# --- functions ---

def save():
    config = {
        'my_text1': my_text1.get(),
        'my_text2': my_text2.get(),
        'my_date': my_date.get(),
    }

    with open("saved_settings.dat", "wb") as pickle_file:
        pickle.dump(config, pickle_file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def clear():
    my_text1.set('')
    my_text2.set('')
    my_date.set('')

def load():
    with open("saved_settings.dat", "rb") as pickle_file:
        config = pickle.load(pickle_file)

    my_text1.set(config.get('my_text1'))
    my_text2.set(config.get('my_text2'))
    my_date.set(config.get('my_date'))


# --- main ---

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

my_text1 = StringVar()
my_text2 = StringVar()
my_date = StringVar()

entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=my_text1)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=my_text2)
entry2.pack()

entry3 = DateEntry(root, textvariable=my_date)
entry3.pack()

Button(root, text="Save Settings", command=save).pack()
Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear).pack()
Button(root, text="Load Settings", command=load).pack()

# load at start
load()

root.mainloop()
```

Instead of `pickle` you can also use [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) or plain text files like JSON, INI, YALM which you can open in text editor and edit, or open in other program (in any other language) which can't use python's pickle.

You can also use database - like `SQLite` which doesn't run server.