# Python3 tkinter. How to make my script remember choices the user made?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have few tkk.CheckButton and ttk.Entry and want it's values, which the users enters there, to be saved after he/she closes the program. And after he/she opens the program for the next time, these values will be where they`ve been left.

Comment: You can use `json` or `pickle` module to save the values and then load them back at program start.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57292295/saving-and-reloading-tkinter-entry-filed-values/57300491#57300491

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you'll probably have to store settings into a file when the user exits the program and load settings from the file when the user relaunches the program.

There are many ways to do this! But off the top of my head, I'd say storing these preferences in a list/dictionary, and then writing it to a file using Pickle, is probably the easiest way!

Pickle examples: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle